How to use sip signling to Implement audio and video calls to webrtc
In Android and iOS client, I use PJSip as signaling, with webrtc to achieve audio and video communication, do not know how to achieve signaling conversion, someone help me？
I am sending events to server using a socket，In fact,  it is server that implements the calling function function
i don`t how to do it，
